# Can I design a logo with white background to be used on products packaging with different background colors?

Tags: logo, background-removal

I'm not a designer. I'm trying to get my logo designed by someone who seems unaware of logo science.

I will be using my logo on multiple products with many different color themes. How do I customize it according to the packaging?

Comment: White is transparent for print processes point of view. Whatever is white will not get printed. On the other hand anything that is printed on any other color substrate will not generrally come out with the color you want. Which is why you want a black only logo so you can use a non transparent ink.

Comment: thankyou for the response

Comment: Tip: get someone who IS a designer and has created logos before to create your logo, you won't have these problems.

Answer (score 1):

"Backgrounds" should really *never* be part of a logo. A logo should stand on its own *without* any "background".

---

Traditionally logos are **not** "customized according to packaging" to any degree.

There may be a few variations of a logo to accommodate usage, but any further degree of customization would be cumbersome and unwieldy.

For example.... FedEx has a few variations for different services.....

[image]

Any subsequent materials related to these services/variations are **adjusted to match the mark** not the other way around. So you create items for FedExGround using green, for FedEx Freight using red, etc.

One would *not* create a package for "FedEx Ground" using purple and royal blue.. then change the logo to match the package. No. You change the package to match the logo.

---

If you require a number of variations for such usage you should communicate that to the designer. Something as simple as..

> We'll need 5 color variations of the logo for packaging.

---

All that being posted. It's not inconceivable that there may be special use cases. But without more specific details it's difficult to provide any feedback.

Comment: Thankyouuuuuuu  cleared many doubts